# Can I send filtered data with Ajax back to PHP file and write them again on page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I implemented my Custom Post Type and content is listed on my page in while loop in that way:

```
 $args = array('post_type' => 'studien', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        if($loop->have_posts()):
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>

        <div class="col-md-6">
         // data are listed here
        </div>
          <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
```

And on my submit I try to filter data according to some custom taxonomies:

```
$ = jQuery;

var search = $("#search-studien");

var searchForm = search.find("studien");

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#studien').submit(function (evt) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = {
            action: "studien_search",
            type: $("#taxonomy-market-type").val(),
        };


        var html;

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

                if(response)
                {
                    // probably here I need to send filtered data back to PHP file and write them again
                }

            }
        });
    })
});
```

I use custom shortcode and callback() function:

```
function search_callback()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

        $type = "";


        $type = $_GET['type'];


    $args = array(
            "post_type" => "studien",
            "post_per_page" => -1,
            "relation" => "AND"
    );


    if($type != "") {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(

            'taxonomy' => 'market',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $type
        );

       $search_query = new WP_Query($args);

       // echo json_encode($search_query);
    }


    else{
        $search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }

    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {

        $result = array();

        while ($search_query->have_posts()) {

            $search_query->the_post();

            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),


            );
        };


        wp_reset_query();

        echo json_encode($search_query);
    }

    else {
        // nothing
    }



    wp_die(); global $argsAjaxFilter;

    $argsAjaxFilter = $search_query;


}
```

As you can see, $search_query represents my filtered data. This is method according to tutorial, but I can`t use response array() ... and best way for me is to send $search_query in some way to PHP file, where I can write my new Custom Post Type data again. Please, someone has advice for me? Is that good proposal?

Comment: You are returning `$search_query` when you should be returning `$result`

Comment: yes, but I need to proccess result in ajax function, and some php variables cannot be replied in javascript string.. that is the reason I need to send new $search_query in some way to my php file... do not like to create html string in ajax response . Also I hope that in response exists some way how to send $search_query back to PHP file and do while loop again, but with filtered data

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. Do you want to render the html response in php or in js ? What the search refining would involve exactly?

Comment: Yes, I would like to render response in php, not in JS.. javascript can not process some php variables. It is main point of my problem, in my example I I have response in JS, but I have to change response to PHP

Comment: "javascript can not process some php variables" In a usual setup, Javascript cannot process *any* PHP variables; it runs on the client side, while PHP is processed on the server. There is server side Javascript like `node.js`, but we're obviously not talking about this here. I think you're confused about AJAX, PHP and JS in general.

Comment: I would say run your `$result` array through the same templates you are using in your "main loop" for your markup. If you need to send additional information, put both that and the html on and object and encode it, but not the WP_Query object itself. I'm guessing `terms` and `post_per_page` is all you need?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is  all I need.. does exist some example, how to do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem is to be able to send the rendered html to the browser. For that, we're going to need a template so we can reuse it in various places.

```
// your-theme/studien.php
<div class="studien-wrapper">
<?php
  if($wp_query->have_posts()):
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
      // Do the thing
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
</div>
```

Next, we need to load it whenever is needed. We can do it by using [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). This function will pass some global variables automatically (such as `$wp_query`) to the template, you can have a look at [the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/template.php#L652) to learn more. When using it in "ajax mode" we need to capture the output, not send it to the browser (although we could) so we use output buffering. For "normal pages" just omit those calls.

```
// Set up query args
global $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
ob_start();  // Capture the output.
get_template_part('studien');
$html_result = ob_get_clean();
```

And now is a matter of composing the response:

```
$result['html'] = $html_result;
if (!is_array($type)) {
  $type = array($type);
}
$result['query_terms'] = $type;

$json = wp_json_encode($result);
echo $json;

wp_die();
```

You could also keep track of the search terms on the client side and avoid the last part. Depends on what you need.

To update the page you can do the following in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.studien-wrapper').replaceWith(response.html);
        // Update search terms, etc
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, but is_array($type)... represents my callback function and according to that filtered data will be returned?

Comment: @MatusVrsansky no, it's just the terms used for the filtering, no callback. I'm being defensive about it since (as I understand) you'll be adding more terms in the future so I'm just ensuring it's an array beforehand.

Comment: Ok, I took your idea and implement custom filter, but is possible to render my custpom post type again with new data from ajax , when is success function ? in console.log everything seems right, but can not refresh my post type with new data

Comment: @MatusVrsansky yes, on your success function you should have access to the array sent from php, you just have to extract the html and insert it on the page