# Can´t correctly write custom field data in custom function placed in functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to write filter data of my custom post type in custom function placed in `functions.php`:

The majority are corrected, but I cannot process these lines:

```
<div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">
  <?php $thumb_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image'),'custom-crop-studien'); ?>
  <img class="img" src="<?php print($thumb_img[0]); ?>">
</div>
```

**and:**

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="cpt-studies-block-link link-read-more"> <?php
  include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
 ?>
 <?php if (get_field('button_text')):
 the_field('button_text');
 else : echo __('More', 'dw');?>
 <?php endif;?>
 </a>
```

Code in folder for writing Custom Post Type data:

```
if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="cpt-studies-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a class="zoom-picture-hover" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                            <div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">
                                <?php $thumb_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image'),'custom-crop-studien'); ?>
                                <img class="img" src="<?php print($thumb_img[0]); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span><?php the_field('date')?></span>
                            <h3>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                                    <?php the_title()?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <p class="cpt-studies-block-text"><?php the_field('text')?></p>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="cpt-studies-block-link link-read-more"> <?php
                              include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
                                ?>
                                <?php if (get_field('button_text')):
                                    the_field('button_text');
                                else : echo __('More', 'dw');?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
```

Code in Custom function in `functions.php`:

```
if(have_posts($wp_query))
   {
       while(have_posts($wp_query))
       {
           the_post();

           echo '<div class="col-md-6">'
            .'<div class="cpt-studies-block">'.
                '<div class="row">'.
                    '<div class="col-md-6">'
                        .'<a class="zoom-picture-hover" href="'.get_permalink().'">'
                            .'<div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">'
            .$thumb_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image'),'custom-crop-studien').
          '<img class="img" src=".print($thumb_img[0]).">'
                            .'</div>'
                        .'</a>'
                    .'</div>'
                    .'<div class="col-md-6">'
                            .'<span>'.get_field('date').'</span>'
                            .'<h3>'
                                .'<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'
                                    .get_the_title().
                                '</a>'
                            .'</h3>'
                            .'<p class="cpt-studies-block-text">'.get_field('text').'</p>'.
                              '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="cpt-studies-block-link link-read-more">'
                                   include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
                            '</a>'.

                    '</div>'.
                '</div>'.
            '</div>'.
        '</div>';
       }
   }
```

Please can someone give me advice, or do I need to change method on writing these lines?

Comment: Do you have an error somewhere ?

Comment: do not have an errors, but data are not written correctly on my page and probably I just need to find way how to get these lines to single or double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a syntax error:

```
.'<div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">'  // Add semicolon.
.$thumb_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
    get_field('image'),'custom-crop-studien').  // Assignement can't be concatenated
    // and missing parenthesis
'<img class="img" src=".print($thumb_img[0]).">'  // Resume echo.
```

So:

```
// Ommited
.'<div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">';
$thumb_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
   get_field('image'), 'custom-crop-studien'));  
echo '<img class="img" src=".print($thumb_img[0]).">'
```

Or better yet, use templates (as I explained in [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461297#answer-52465990))